# How to activate IDEA's "Run Dashboard" feature

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a window tool named "**Run Dashboard**" in Project A, but I can't activate this window in Project B. Does anyone know how to solve this? This feature appeared in IntelliJ IDEA version 2017.3.

This is what I see in Project A:
[image: long menu of run-related buttons with "Run Dashboard" button at end]

This is what I see in Project B:
[image: menu of run-related buttons similar to the one in Project A, but without the "Run Dashboard" button]

This option is present but not activatable out in Project B:
[image: screenshot of search for "Run Dashboard" feature showing it grayed out]

but it's activatable in Project A:
[image: screenshot of search for "Run Dashboard" feature showing it selectable]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Add the run configurations to the **Configurations available in Run Dashboard** list in the [Edit Run/Debug Configurations dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) under the **Defaults** (**Templates** in the [current IDE versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtMoq.png)) node:

[image: dashboard]

In Spring Boot projects Run Dashboard becomes enabled automatically if you have more than one run/debug configuration of this type.

Comment: Also it allows to add tomcat server runtime configuration to Run Dashboard, which is really helpful when one project has spring-boot modules and traditional web application module at the same time, and you want to run them side by side. Switching between two different run-consoles is harmful. :)

Comment: thank you for showing how to disable this poc, if you accidentally hide the logs of running app, dashboard disappears and never comes back, if you run two apps, 2nd one hides the first, truely aweful stuff jetbrains

Comment: Great feature ! I thought it was limited to spring boot projects but with this post I now can also add node (or any other type of) projects

Comment: Thanks! That's a well hidden settings control ;-) never had the idea to click that Edit Configurations Template tree node other than for expand/collapse *clapping-forehead* - finally, I can disable automatic Run Dashboard for my spring boot based services - what a relief

Comment: I am using version 2020.1 but not able to see spring dashboard. Any idea how to enable the same?

Answer (score 6):

***In Intellij 2020*** now Dashboard is by the name of **Services** see below screenshot and by default, the view is like this 
[image]

To get back to the old view of the **initial version of spring-dashboard**.

Right-click on Services -> Enable '**Show Service Tree**'

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

@CrazyCoder is right, you need to have more than one "Spring boot run/debug configuration". Try to duplicate the one you already have and IntelliJ will automaticaly prompt you to run the dashboard.

Comment: fun thing is that if you remove the newly created configuration after you activated the run configuration, it stays there for good (at least this happens on 2018.2)

Answer (score 3):

I use Idea 2019.3 and this is how I managed to activate it.

1. Open Services Tool Window (my shortcut is ALT+8)
2. Add your Spring boot application if Idea didn't automatically recognized it.

[image: Services window shortcut for faster opening]

[image: Services Window]

Comment: in Idea 2020 I added Spring Boot but it showed as "Spring Boot" not like yours "Run Dashboard", but seems like it has same functionalities

Answer (score 3):

I use IntelliJ IDEA ULTIMATE 2019.1 version.

Steps to activate the feature: Run -> Edit Configurations...-> Templates -> Add "**Spring Boot**"

[image]

Comment: In 2020.1 they call it "Services". Wish they'd quit changing it.

Answer (score 0):

My project is Spring Cloud project. So I add Spring Boot with the below flow. 
**Edit Configuratio**n
[image]
Select **Default** > **Configurations available in Run Dashboard** > add **Spring Boot**  > **Apply** > **OK**
[image]
Then we can see the **Run Dashboard** view in the left down side.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

step1: enter "Services" tag
[image]

step2: click on "add service" and choose "Add Configuration Type" with "Spring boot" selected.
[image]