# Spring Boot run dashboard missing from Intellij IDEA 2018.2

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018

I have added the Custom VM Option `-Dide.run.dashboard=true` in Help -> Edit custom VM options. But I cannot seem to find this "Run Dashboard" for Spring boot that which is mentioned in this JetBrains blog post https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/05/intellij-idea-2017-2-eap-run-dashboard-for-spring-boot/

I have tried looking at JetBrains blog posts but cannot seem to find what happened to this Dashboard in 2018.2 version of Intellij IDEA.

Comment: Do you use the Community or the paid version? Only the Ultimate contains spring features. Proof: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

Comment: @appl3r I am checking out the Ultimate version's (2018.2) free trial

Comment: The behavior was changed in a new release. Follow this advice:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49424397/8958060

Comment: @PetrRastegaev I am not seeing that option at all. I saw that answer but "Run Dashboard" is not coming at all anywhere even in the action dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

My Intellij IDEA version is 2018.1, and I encounter the same problem as first. It did not work after changing `-Dide.run.dashboard=true` to idea.exe.vmoptions and idea64.exe.vmoptions.

I found another way to get "Run Dashboard" back again.

In your Spring Boot or Spring Cloud project, open the `workspace.xml` in `.idea` directory (in the top level directory):
[image: workspace.xml]

Find the tag `component` with the name property `RunDashboard`, at first, it should be like this:

```xml
<component name="RunDashboard">
    <option name="ruleStates">
      <list>
        <RuleState>
          <option name="name" value="ConfigurationTypeDashboardGroupingRule" />
        </RuleState>
        <RuleState>
          <option name="name" value="StatusDashboardGroupingRule" />
        </RuleState>
      </list>
    </option>
</component>
```

Next, add the following code to the `component` tag, along with the existing `option` tag:

```xml
<option name="configurationTypes">
    <set>
        <option value="SpringBootApplicationConfigurationType" />
    </set>
</option>
```

Finally, it should be like this:

```xml
<component name="RunDashboard">
    <option name="configurationTypes">
        <set>
            <option value="SpringBootApplicationConfigurationType" />
        </set>
    </option>
    <option name="ruleStates">
        <list>
        <RuleState>
            <option name="name" value="ConfigurationTypeDashboardGroupingRule" />
        </RuleState>
        <RuleState>
            <option name="name" value="StatusDashboardGroupingRule" />
        </RuleState>
        </list>
    </option>
</component>
```

Then, just press Ctrl+S (Save this file), and the "Run Dashboard" will pop up!